# Hyperlink block element doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, hyperlink, block, href, explorer

My head is about to explode after looking into why this is not working for me.  All is ok in Firefox but in IE nothing shows up to click unless I have text or something in the `<a>`'s.  I've searched for a long time and would prefer not using un-needed .gifs.  You can ignore the high z-index values.  I've also tried putting `<a>` in a `<span>`.  Basically what I want is an empty div and empty a that links to an image.

```
.gallery
{
position:absolute;
width:400px;
height:100px;
margin-left:300px;
margin-top:0px;
z-index:1000000;
}

.gallery a 
{
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
width:400px;
height:100px;
z-index:999999999;
}

<div class=\"gallery\"><a title=\"Front Entrance of the new Pontiac branch.\" href=\"images/Pontiac/P5020002.JPG\"></a></div>
```

Comment: If the `<a>` is empty, what are they supposed to click on?

Comment: What do you expect to acomplish with an empty anchor?  There's nothing to click.

Comment: It's working fine in IE as long as i set a background-color so that i can see where the `<a>` is to click on it.

Comment: You guys obviously have never coded a site. Elements in the DOM don't have to have content to be clickable... jesus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is IE needs a background. You can fool it with a spacer image or just a dummy image like:

```
background:url(/no-image.jpg);
```

That should fix it.

Comment: This looks like it will work...Will any browser display the image missing red X or what have you?

Comment: Not with a background image. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're using that HTML directly, but you don't have to escape the double quotes.

Your example works for me in IE once I fixed the quote issue: http://jsfiddle.net/U2yeJ/

Are you sure you clicked in the right area?

Comment: I have the slashes because I output via PHP - I removed them but am still getting the same problem.

Comment: @and_27_y - In that case, you should keep them. Can you post an example page showing your problem? Did you trying setting a background colour on the `<a>` element to show where it is. Maybe it's not appearing where you think.

Comment: Just put a red background - which i can click - when I remove the background:red; there is nothing to click on.

Comment: @and_27_y - I see what you mean. Very strange. Well perhaps you could try what Oscar Godson suggested. Is there any way you can change around your code so that the `<a>` has something in it. Why do you have invisible anchors anyways? If it's for a gallery, why not just wrap the images in anchor's directly?

Comment: I guess there is no reason that I cannot do it that way - I was just trying to not have to splice the image and then place that image behind another image.  This seemed like a much easier way of doing things if it only worked in IE!!  Here is the site [link](http://streatoronized.org) - I put in Oscars fix.